# Control Panel access. Greyed out button

Tags: control-panel

The Admin login screen for my site is not working.

The button to submit my credentials is greyed out and submission by pressing enter is not working either.

Not sure how to go about solving this one or updated the site to fix it if there is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was a bug and a patch was duly applied.

Thanks for the patch Brad.

Answer (score 1):

If your look at your browser's console on that page you'll see your getting several JavaScript errors:

[image]

Which seems to indicate that some of your files didn't FTP up properly and are corrupted.  Try re-uploading your files and make sure your FTP client is set to transfer in 'auto' mode.

Comment: Crap.

I've not been FTPing I've been using Git.

Now that I've forced a pull, I've brought down that site.

`Craft does not support backtracking to this version.`

Comment: Oh, along with some deploy tool?  I'd guess a file didn't get deployed properly then.  Try and redo it?

Comment: See above edited comment

Comment: Now somehow the files in craft/app are older than the database schema that you have in the database.  You can compare version/build/schema version in the craft_info table to the same values in craft/app/Info.php.

Comment: So the info.php tells me

`define('CRAFT_VERSION', '2.0');
define('CRAFT_BUILD', '2539');
define('CRAFT_SCHEMA_VERSION', '2.0.1');`

And the DB tells me

`Version 2.0 Build 2528 Scheme 2.0.0`

How can I update my repo to the Version/Build/Scheme in the live DB?

Comment: If I update my local instance to the current build and then push to the server will this work?

Comment: I'd put the 2528 (or later) files in place with the 2528 database (you can download 2528 here http://download.buildwithcraft.com/craft/2.0/2.0.2539/Craft-2.0.2539.zip) or download the latest from buildwithcraft.com and let it perform the update.

Comment: Both the files and DB are now at current.

Javascript error has returned and occurs only on server and not on local machine :-/

Thoughts?

Comment: If you want to send some CP/FTP credentials over to support@buildwithcraft.com, we can look at it and I'll update the answer here with the result.