# Login grayed out, logins rejected

Tags: login

We have web site with CraftCMS Pro 2.6.2930. Due to development of new site, we set test web server (Centos/Apache/mariaDB) in our local network and migrated whole site there for testing (2.6.2993 with trial license). Site is working, but logins to craft admin webpage are rejected (log in button is greyed out).

For migration i have followed this [Migration of Craft CMS from one host to another](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13982/migration-of-craft-cms-from-one-host-to-another) (we deleted license.key file)

Craft/storage/runtime/logs shows

2018/05/17 13:45:58 [warning] [application]  tried to log in unsuccessfully.

Site content is migrated successfully.

PS: I've already tried this and it isn't working: [Reset password with MySQL](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13781/reset-password-with-mysql/13966#13966)

Any ideas?

PS: It seems my problem is very similar to this one [Control Panel access. Greyed out button](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1855/control-panel-access-greyed-out-button) since i see (almost the same) errors

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors in your browser's console on the login page?

Comment: @BradBell yes there are 9 errors shown https://imgur.com/ZbwsvGp

Comment: btw i'm not so deep into web or craft so i could interpret it. Since similar question exists, i've uploaded all files again to the server via WinSCP using "auto" option for transfer type, but no luck there

Comment: What do you get when you try to load that first JS file in a browser? i.e. http://yoursite.com/admin/resources/lib/d3/d3.min.js

Comment: it is d3.min.js file https://imgur.com/OB6TIzV Permissions are 777

Comment: Weird... if you want to send some CP and (s)FTP/SSH credentials over to support@craftcms.com, we can poke around a bit.

Comment: I've solved the problem! I guess all those files (showing erros) were somehow corrupted during download from web server in production. I've  downloaded and copied all those files again and voila, it works!! However huge THANKS to Brad for pointing me in the right direction by looking browser console!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!  Would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer? Might end up helping someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved! So, the console clearly showed which files were broken.

I've downloaded those files again from production server, and uploaded on my test server. Login succeed without any problems now!

I guess it has something to do with transfer mode (auto, binary, text etc) when transferring files via FTP. Transfer mode should be on auto, otherwise files might get corrupted which can cause all kind of (weird) problems. Thanks to Brad for help!

Comment: This begs for some automation of the deployment process, this might be useful to you: [Website Deployment without Tears](https://devmode.fm/episodes/website-deployment-without-tears)